# style.clip in JavaScript change over time

Tags: javascript, css, html, clip

I am still new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript so I am not sure of what can and can not be done. I am trying to use the clip property to reveal a div over time. Is this possible and if so how? I can only seem to access clip in JavaScript using quotations (ex. element.style.clip = "rect(x, x, x, x)".

I would like to have it read element.style.clip = "rect(x, x, scalerValuepx, x)".

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without knowing much about your intended use of clip on a div, I would probably recommend giving the div in question overflow-y: hidden with CSS and gradually increasing the CSS height of the element until it is fully revealed.

There's some really easy to use animation methods in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that do this, such as [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

Comment: I am creating an effect that will animate a line out from a click point on screen. Once the line is complete a div will be displayed but hidden. I am using clip to hide the div when it is first shown then change the bottom value so that it looks as though the div is expanding revealing the contents of it. I hope this explains a little bit more of what I am going for. The big thing is I want to do this time based so it syncs up with my time based line animation.

Comment: slideDown() is built exactly for this, and handles the animation for you. Learning the fundamentals of Javascript and CSS without jQuery is a great exercise, but this is the sort of thing jQuery was built for so I would give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you Wayne I will take a look at it now.